# how to solve this Incorrect type return in F#

Tags: f#

I have a function that starts with:

```
type Coordinate = (int * int)
type ColourList = byte list
type Block = Coordinate * ColourList

makeBlock(image:image) (coord:Coordinate) : Block =
    Block(coord,getColourList(image(coord))`

CreateUnit (image:Image) : (Coordinate -> Block) =
    fun coord -> makeBlock(image, coord)`
```

`getColourList` is getting RGB byteList in a coordinate of a picture. Its signature is

```
image:Image -> x:int * y:int -> byte list
```

We know that image is also a type and my problem is the return type of that getColourList(image(coord)) is `int * int -> byte list` which is an incorrect expression. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks for answering

Comment: I don't understand well the question, but your function signature tells that: "CreateUnit is a function that takes an image as input and returns **another function** that accepts Coordinate as input and returns Block". So later you could do something like `let block = CreateUnit image coordinate`

Comment: yeah so how to create that function is my question
am i going to make something like `let Unit (??param):(Block)` ?
I dont know what kind of things i should type in. And how to return that **another function** as the output

Comment: What happens when you change `getColourList(image(coord))` to `getColorList image coord`?  The expression as you've written it attempts to treat image like a function.

Comment: I took the liberty of improving the formatting of your code. If you have code blocks, you don't need to put backticks around them; just indent them by four characters and they will show up correctly formatted. There's a handy button that looks like `{}` in the Stack Overflow editor box that will do this for you, so you can just paste your code, highlight it, click the `{}` button, and you're done. (Look at the preview below the edit box to see if you did it right).

Comment: finally solved, thanks Robert Sim's comment here, the problem is just the bracket...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question I think what you are asking is how to define the function returned by CreateUnit. It depends a little on how you make blocks from images and coordinates. Suppose it's a member function of image:

```
let CreateUnit image : (Coordinate->Block) =
    fun (coordinate:Coordinate) -> image.makeBlock(coordinate)
```

This will give you a function bound to the image that takes coordinates and generates blocks:

```
let myImage = loadImage(filename)
let blockMaker = CreateUnit image

myCoordinates
|> Seq.map blockMaker
```

will transform a sequence of coordinates into a sequence of blocks derived from the image.